# ViewPager in TabFragment is not loading a second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I'm trying to make an app that has a `ViewPager` in a Fragment that is part of a `TabHost`. Everything works out fine. I have my tabbar, I can switch tabs. When I switch to the tab with the `ViewPager`, all is shown correctly.

However, as soon as I leave this tab with the `ViewPager` and return this tab, my content is not shown. If I scroll to the side twice I do see my next image and if I go back two times I also see the images are loaded (probably the `offscreenloaded`).

See that my `TabFragment` is being reinstantiated when I return to it but the fragments in the `ViewPager` aren't.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mProjectText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.projectText);
    mProjectText.setText(mActiveProject.getInspirationText());

    mAdapter = new AlbumAdapter(getFragmentManager(), mActiveProject.getInspiration());

    mPager = (ViewPager)getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

public class AlbumAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<ProjectContent> mItems;

public AlbumAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<ProjectContent> items) {
    super(fm);
    this.mItems = items;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return AlbumContentFragment.newInstance(mItems.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}}
```

[image: The mockup for the app]

Answer (score 196, accepted):

I found the problem. It took me two days, but hey, it's fixed.

Instead of using

```
mAdapter = new AlbumAdapter(getFragmentManager(), mActiveProject.getInspiration());
```

You should use

```
mAdapter = new AlbumAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mActiveProject.getInspiration());
```

So much for 5 characters.

Comment: Man you never know how you saved my ass tonight!

Comment: By the way don't bother looking for something like getSupportChildFragmentManager() since getChildFragmentManager() is a method of Fragment and not of Activity...

Comment: Perfect, mate, would never have found this without your post.

Comment: It works, but second time if we open fragment, it takes 1 second of lag to display first tab listview. Any solution?

Comment: Thanks! This is because we're adding a fragment in a fragment right? But if it's in an Activity, it should be `getFragmentManager()`? This actually made my day man thanks

Comment: How did *oogle expect developers to be able to know such thing? Awful design. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 49):

I been searching
 this for long finally found a solution.Change your page adapter instance `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
example:

```
class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
```

Comment: Than you, after FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter it is working. It is Simple and Short answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Spent to much time on this problem and your simple change worked.

Comment: OMG, it resolve me problem, but i found a problem with dynamic height of Fragment in ViewPager, my void OnMeasure can't get height of view when showing at second time.

Comment: The correct answer is the other, but this also works. Thank you all.

Comment: While this works, this does change how the Fragments are loaded and kept in memory. If you want the behavior of a FragmentPagerAdapter, the other solution is the right one.

Answer (score 8):

you should use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter()` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter()`.Hope it will be useful for someone.

Comment: Hey can you please explain why using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` over `FragmentPagerAdapter` works?