# Android ActionBar with 3 tab viewpager issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-actionbar-compat

i had create 3 tab with view pager. There is an issue is that **in all 3 tab i had save and exit button but when i swipe page one two time and pres on save or exit button it will not work** becuse when move to second fragment if call third fragment view.

```
public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener, OnPageChangeListener {
private String TAG = "FrmLsAdd: ";
private static String[] TestAr = new String[3];
private AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.farmer_add);
    TestAr[0] = "Create  1";
    TestAr[1] = "Create 2";
    TestAr[2] = "Create  3";
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
        actionBar.setTitle("Farmer");
    }
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    String TAG = "Apdtr: ";

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment mFragment = new Fragment();
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                AppLog.logString(TAG + "case 0");
                mFragment = Fragment1.newInstance(i);
                break;

            case 1:
                AppLog.logString(TAG + "case 1");
                mFragment = Fragment2.newInstance(i);
                break;

            case 2:
                AppLog.logString(TAG + "case 2");
                mFragment = Fragment3.newInstance(i);
                break;

            default:
                AppLog.logString(TAG + "Default");
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: " + i);
        }
        return mFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TestAr[(position)];
    }
}

public static class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private String TAG = "Frg1: ";
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private static Fragment1 f;

    static Fragment1 newInstance(int num) {
        f = new Fragment1();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "onCreate");
        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.farmer_add1, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "onCreateView");
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "onActivityCreated");
        ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSave))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        AppLog.logString(TAG + "onbtnSave");
                    }
                });

        ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnCancel))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        final Dialog Alert_Dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}

public static class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    private String TAG = "Frg2: ";
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private static Fragment2 f;

    static Fragment2 newInstance(int num) {
        f = new Fragment2();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "onCreate");
        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.farmer_add2, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "onCreateView");
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        AppLog.logString(TAG + "onActivityCreated");
        ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSave))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        AppLog.logString(TAG + "onbtnSave");
                    }
                });
        ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnCancel))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    }

    public static class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
        private String TAG = "Frg3: ";
        private DatabaseHandler db;
        private static Fragment3 f;

        static Fragment3 newInstance(int num) {
            f = new Fragment3();
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            AppLog.logString(TAG + "onCreate");
            db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.farmer_add3, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            AppLog.logString(TAG + "onCreateView");
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            AppLog.logString(TAG + "onActivityCreated");

            ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSave))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        }
                    });

            ((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnCancel))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.close();
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // mViewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(this.getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
}
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960676/viewpager-in-tabfragment-not-loading-second-time/16983579#16983579

Comment: @DaanOlislagers cannot get getChildFragmentManager.